# How to use custom django filters passing string parameters?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I made a new filter in django. Its name is iarray and this is its definition:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def iarray(value, arg):
    """
    This return the value of dict in arg index:: value[arg]
    :param value:
    :return:
    """
    value = eval(value)
    return value[str(arg)]
```

In theory, this function should return the value of a dict in a given position.

The problem is when templates are rendering. 
For example:

```
"text": "<h1>Holguín</h1><br /><p>{{ provincias|iarray:'Holguín'|safe }}</p>"...
```

The above code throws the following exception:

Error during template rendering

```
In template /srv/www/eicma/templates/eicma/index7.html, error at line 527 (the above line).
```

The trouble is in production mode, in dev mode the trouble doesn't exist.
This is a more complete example of code:

```
mapData.paths = [
                            {
                                "enable": true,
                                "name": "Holguín",
                                "abbreviation": "HO",
                                "textX": 0,
                                "textY": 0,
                                "color": "#59798e",
                                "hoverColor": "#E32F02",
                                "selectedColor": "#feb41c",
                                "url": "#",
                                "text": "<h1>Holguín</h1><br /><p>{{ provincias|iarray:'Holguín'|safe }}</p>",
                                "path": "M610.5,166.9 L610.8,167.7 L606.2,167.1 L604.5,165.7 L604.4,164.5 L607.6,163.8 L609.0,164.4 Z M555.8,134.0 L558.3,135.8 .... Z"
                            },
```

So, my question is the following:

1. It's something wrong? Of course, I loaded filters and added to
   INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Could you post a more complete extract of your template?

Comment: But the js script is inside the template no?

Comment: Yes, it's. It's inside a <script> tag inside an .html file....the same where {% load eicma_filters %} are loaded. eicma_filters is the file inside templatetags app where custom filter was written.

Comment: You should not post an answer to add such information, but edit your question

Comment: Done!! It was removed!!

Comment: But you haven't shown the error. Nor have you explained what that filter is trying to do. What is `privincias`, and why does it need to be `eval`ed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but here are some ideas you could try to better identifying the origin of the problem: remove special characters, move this line directly in the static html, test with only one filter, use double quotes instead of single...

Comment: I just fixed a percent of trouble...I was not sending, in prod mode, a dict.. When it was solved, I found another issue. So, thanks for everything!!!